# How to prevent nginx from reverse proxy specific subdirectories

Tags: linux, nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

On Apache you can ProxyPass everything except one or more subdirectories (with "!").

```
    ProxyPass /subdir !
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:9999/
```

What is the Nginx equivalent ?

My first guess is obviously not working :

```
 location /subdir {
      root /var/www/site/subdir;
  }

 location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:9999/ ;
  }
```

Answer (score 15):

You can bind the proxy_pass to EXACTLY the path you like, like this

```
location = / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9999/;
}
```

This makes sure that no other path will be passed but `/`

OR

you can use this syntax for just the subdirectories to be matched

```
location ^~ /subdir {
     alias /var/www/site/subdir;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9999/ ;
}
```

The `^~` matches the subdir and then stops searching so the `/` will not be executed. It is described [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location).

Comment: root /var/www/site/subdir should be root /var/www/site in my case, otherwise nginx will try to access /var/www/site/subdir/subdir .

Comment: You are right. Either that, or you can use `alias` instead of `root`

Comment: Could you explain this `^~` more? I could not get what does it do. I tried reading the link you sent, but still cannot get it. *If the longest matching prefix location has the “^~” modifier then regular expressions are not checked.*

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin it essentially means that it tries to match a prefix on a path and does not evaluate regular expressions.

Comment: Actually my problem is with this word *prefix*: does it here mean the fix string (simple non-regex string)?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin it is the first part of the path that you want to use for the location. And yes it is without regex.